# How to create H2 database Trigger from JPA Entities?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, h2, database-trigger

In my Spring Boot Application I'm creating a schema from my JPA Entities, but I'm not able to create a trigger (`lastModificationDate`) that can be shown in the DB.

I used the `@EntityListeners` annotation, but after application launched, when I execute a simple insertion command in the H2 Portal, the value of my column is still `null`.

Normally I want to have a trigger declared on my `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

```
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Entity
public class CommonEntity {

  @LastModifiedDate
  private Timestamp lastModified;
  ....
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JPA is not a technology for creating database triggers. You use the H2 console for that

Comment: But JPA can make constraints... and Listeners are made for that job I think. No ?

Comment: A listener is made to inform a user that something is happening. The only "constraints" that a JPA provider can apply in a datastore is at schema generation time, for indexes, uniques, and FKs ... and none of them are triggers